# PDE Build vs. Maven Tycho

Tags: maven, osgi, eclipse-rcp, tycho

In [A Brief Overview of Building at Eclipse](https://wiki.eclipse.org/A_Brief_Overview_of_Building_at_Eclipse#Cross-platform_build) it is mentioned that the PDE build is the 'old way' of building RCP-based applications. I wonder:

1. Why it is considered outdated?
2. What are the advantages of Tycho over PDE?
3. Is the 'old way' going to deprecate?

Comment: PDE build is already deprecated, bugs in it are not being fixed. Tycho is the only build you should consider.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PDE Build has been deprecated in Eclipse Neon (4.6) more than four years ago.

See [Eclipse 4.6 review](https://projects.eclipse.org/projects/eclipse/releases/4.6.0/review):

> PDE Build is in maintenance mode and is no longer used to build the
> Eclipse platform itself

The advantage of Tycho, besides being newer, is the bootstrapping ability inherited from Maven. This allows you to build an Eclipse plugin, product, update site, etc. wherever Maven is supported, for example on GitHub in a workflow action.